# How to adding code to object at runtime ? - Livecode

Tags: livecode

everyone.I have any idea to adding code to object at runtime.But I have some problem.

If that object have script and I want to adding code to object by keep old script of object.

How do I do ?

Here my code :

```
put "on preOpencard" & return & "playani" & return & "end preOpencard" into Ascript[sA]
set the script of the last card of stack stackN to Ascript[sA]
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To append the existing script;

```
put "on preOpencard" & return & "playani" & return & "end preOpencard" into Ascript[sA]
put the script of the last card of stack stackN & return & return & Ascript[sA] into tNewScript
set the script of the last card of stack stackN to tNewScript
```

Answer (score 0):

The ideas here are sound, but we must be careful to maintain the control structures, that is, to make sure that we start the script with "on" and end it with "end".

So it is important to test this, and generically, to place the new modified code BEFORE the last line of the existing script. That usually entails a generous use of returns, and specifically, the insertion of a return, prepended to the new code snippet, AFTER line "-2" of the existing code:

put return & yourNewCode after line -2 of yourOldScript

set the script of yourObject to yourOldScript

Craig Newman

Comment: I think @dunbarx means that if you want to add lines to an existing preOpenCard handler or there is already one in the script, then simply appending to the script won't do. You'd have to search the script for "end preOpenCard", for example using the offset function, then insert your code before that if offset()found something. Even then a "return" statement somewhere above  in the existing handler could make your code not run.